# How do keep memory usage and size of application down (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, ios4

I am currently working on a personal iPhone project that is very audio and graphic-intense and I have therefore been quite conscious of how much of a footprint my application has (in terms of both memory usage while active and/or in 'multi-tasking mode' and how much the size of application is) as Apple sub-consciously gets into my mind and has drilled in the fact the iPhone has limited memory and capacity - and I was curious if any of you guys had any solutions that could help me keep down the usage of my application - I've open up Instruments and configured some aspects although this primarily appeals to me as a performance utility). I have also been testing on my device as I cannot stand the simulator...

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are properly releasing objects that aren't being used, you should be fine. If you are loading large images and audio files, then your app will require more memory to handle those, so alloc/release those as they are needed.

Also, debugging memory issues on the Simulator just wont work, so don't rely on it for testing memory issues.